# primeng - Tree - Folders static and not interactive

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to add primeng Tree to my angular app. I'm using angular 4 (4.0) with webpack.

In webpack, i have added the following:

```
'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
'primeng/primeng',
'primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css',
'primeng/resources/primeng.min.css',
```

If for example i check the bundled css, it seems like everything is in and working.

I have imported the Tree Menu into my app.module

```
import { TreeModule } from "primeng/components/tree/tree";
```

and added it to the imports

```
imports: [TreeModule]
```

I'm using lazy loading, so i've added this again to my lazy loaded module.

I'm trying to add the [example](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tree) so in my actual component i've added the following.

```
import { TreeNode } from "primeng/primeng";
```

This is my template

```
<p-tree [value]="files"></p-tree>
```

It shows the following folder structure but if i click on the folder it doesn't expand. It's completely static but i'm guessing that it must be working in some way as it displaying the top level items.

[image]

Comment: what's your files? Show the `children ` what you set completely.

Comment: It's the same as the ngprime example - https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/assets/showcase/data/files.json

Comment: Do you have an error in your browser javascript console when the tree compnent is shown or when you click on the tree node?

Comment: No errors shown anywhere

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in a Plunker maybe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated all angular packages to 4.4.5 and everything started working